# Excel double negative operator with logical operators

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula, operators

I've just learned about double operators and am wondering if you can add logical operators to increase the range looked at. For example if any cell in the range A1:A10 is less 10 AND any corresponding cell next to that particular cell in the range B1:B10 is greater than 5 then sum the values in the corresponding cell in the range C1:C10.
This is clearly not correct, but I would have thought it would have been written something like this.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(AND(A1:A10<10,B1:B10>5)),C1:C10)
```

The normal -- function is:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A1:A10<10),C1:C10)
```

Comment: Use `SUMIFS` =)

Comment: `AND` returns a single value.  You need to return an array of values if you want to do a line by line comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you multiply, you don't need the double-negative:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A10<10)*(B1:B10>5)*(C1:C10))
```

for example:

[image]

Comment: @g sure:  ***=SUMPRODUCT(--(A1:A10<10),--(B1:B10>5),(C1:C10))***

Comment: Fantastic . Slight tweek turns out " ,(C1:C10)" should be " *(C1:C10)"

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Sumifs, it put many criterias you want to sum a column.

```
 =Sumifs(C1:C10;B1:B10;">5";A1:A10;"<10")
```